# Simple code on Octave

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, octave

In my case `u` is a vector of random numbers

```
 for i=u

   if (i<1)

     i=i+1

   endif

 endfor
```

in the end it gives me only the vector `i=u`

Comment: What are you trying to do??? If you post code that is wrong, and no hint at what the desired output should be, how can anyone help you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to count the number of elements less than one then:

```
sum(u < 1)
```

Or if you wanted to use a loop then you need a separate variable for the total:

```
count = 0
for i = u
    if i < 1
        count = count+1;
    end
end
```